# How to call the event of specific button in an updatepanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events, updatepanel

I have the following case :

an `updatepanel` with the following triggers :

```
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtn_addApp" EventName="Click" />
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_agree" />
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_disagree" />
</Triggers>
```

---

Now i wanna to fire the click event of `btn_disagree` so i do :

```
    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       btn_disagree_Click(null, null);
    }
```

---

**Note** : `btn_submit` in the updatepanel

but when i call the click event , it doesn't make the postbak !!

how i call the `btn_disagree` event with postback behavior

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do.  Being asynchronous, and `UpdatePanel` doesn't perform post-backs by design.  If you want the page to perform a normal post-back, why not use a normal button?  And what exactly are you trying to accomplish by calling an event handler from within an event handler?  Handlers are for UI events, don't call them manually.  Instead, re-factor whatever logic is in `btn_disagree_Click` into its own method and call that method.

Comment: I have two states `asynchronousTrigger` & `PostBackTrigger` so i need an update panel just i wanna when calling the `btn_disagree_Click` to perform the same behavior of `PostBackTrigger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `btn_submit`?

According to your markup, clicking on `btn_disagree` should cause a standard post-back.  But according to your code, you're not clicking on `btn_disagree`.  You're clicking on something called `btn_submit`, which isn't listed in your triggers.

If `btn_submit` is also part of the `UpdatePanel` and you want `btn_submit` to also cause a post-back, you'll need to include a `PostBackTrigger` for it.  Otherwise it will use the default behavior of an `UpdatePanel` and call the server asynchronously.

On a side note, this code needs a little refactoring:

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_disagree_Click(null, null);
}
```

You should avoid calling event handlers directly.  They're meant to respond to UI events.  Calling them directly (and passing `null`s and such) makes for a pretty messy experience and is just asking for bugs and odd behavior.

What this code implies to me is that there is important business logic inside of `btn_disagree_Click` which needs to be used from `btn_submit_Click`.  That business logic should be refactored into another method all its own.  Then the two event handlers can simply call that method, instead of trying to call each other.

Let the handlers just handle UI events and direct control to business logic.  Keep the business logic separate from the UI code.

Comment: `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_submit" EventName="click" />`
I wanna to in the case of calling  ` btn_disagree_Click(null, null);` in  `btn_submit_Click` make the post back otherwise the default behavior `AsyncPostBack`

Comment: @just_name: It doesn't work that way.  In the markup you posted in your comment, you are _explicitly_ telling the code to use _asynchronous_ behavior for `btn_submit`.  Why would you ever expect synchronous behavior when you're configuring it not to do that?  When you try to manually call `btn_disagree_Click()` on the server, you can't initiate a post-back because you're already *on the server*.  There is no post-back from the server, only from the client, and by this time the client is no longer involved.

Comment: @just_name: Post-backs happen from the client-side, not from the server-side.  The _client_ needs to know to post back to the server, otherwise it won't post back.  You'll need to either explicitly configure the button that's being clicked to post back to the server or perform whatever conditional logic you imply is in `btn_submit_Click` on the client-side and manually perform the post-back on your condition (using JavaScript, which would get messy since you'd be hooking into existing generated JavaScript from the framework).

Answer (score 0):

```
 </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>  
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Submit_But" EventName="click" />  
   </Triggers>  
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```